# incorrect architecture in 3u tools from clickteam project

Tags: xcode6

I'm not good at xcode (I have xcode 6.2, os x 10.9) I can develop games on clickteam fusion and port them to "legacy ios" in particular ios 6, there was a problem with my second port. In ios simulator, the game runs correctly, but when installed on iphone (5, ios 6), for example through 3u tools, it writes incorrect architecture. If installed via the ipa installer, (this is an ios tweak) then he writes that the ipa cannot be installed. What should I do with this, I have no idea(

I tried to delete all the ini files, but it didn't help, if anything, architecture specified arm64, arm7, arm7s